# Connection between subnets on different interfaces without IP forwarding

Tags: networking, routing, forwarding

This is my first question on superuser, so I apologize if it is not up to par.

I'm running pop!_OS 19.10 (Ubuntu 19.10 based) and am trying to understand its network behaviour. Given the network interface `eth0`, I added the following subnets:

```
ip addr add dev eth0 192.168.2.18/24
ip addr add dev eth0 192.168.3.18/24
```

The interface now looks as follows (MAC-Address changed)

```
1: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.18/24 scope global enp0s31f6
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.3.18/24 scope global enp0s31f6
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Using `nc`, I can send data between the IP-addresses `192.168.2.18` and `192.168.3.18`.

```sh
##################################################################################
# nc -v -l 192.168.2.18 8080
Listening on [pop-os] (family 2, port 8080)
Listening on pop-os 8080
Connection received on pop-os 55361
Hello World!
##################################################################################
# nc -v -s 192.168.3.18 192.168.2.18 8080
Connection to 192.168.2.18 8080 port [tcp/http-alt] succeeded!
Hello World!
##################################################################################
# ss -4 -n
tcp    ESTAB    0    0    192.168.3.18:55361    192.168.2.18:8080           
tcp    ESTAB    0    0    192.168.2.18:8080     192.168.3.18:55361
```

**Question #1:** Am I right to assume that addresses within **separate subnets** on the **same interface** can always communicate with each other (unless blocked by a firewall)? Is this because the Kernel looks into the routing table and sees that it can simply locally connect the two networks? I.e.:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.3.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Now I tested this, because I was looking into Kernel IP-Forwarding and read [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/248841/ip-forwarding-when-and-why-is-this-required):

> However, if forwarding is turned off, the kernel will first check to
>   see which interface the packet came from. If it didn't come from the
>   same interface, the kernel will discard it.

However, I can also connect to `192.168.2.18` through my other interface `wlan0`, using the address `192.168.1.73`. I have IP forwarding disabled.

```
Netid    State  Recv-Q  Send-Q    Local Address:Port  Peer Address:Port           
tcp      ESTAB  0       0         192.168.2.18:8080   192.168.1.73:40405          
tcp      ESTAB  0       0         192.168.1.73:40405  192.168.2.18:8080
```

**Question #2:** Why can IP addresses on different subnets & interfaces communicate without IP forwarding enabled? Is it because they belong to the same host? Where is this behavior defined? I.e. would IP forwarding rules only kick in once packets start leaving the host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question #1: Am I right to assume that addresses within separate subnets on the same interface can always communicate with each other (unless blocked by a firewall)? Is this because the Kernel looks into the routing table and sees that it can simply locally connect the two networks? I.e.:

Yes. This isn't caused by the "subnet" entries that you found, but rather by "local address" entries that are in a separate routing table (the 'local' table). The old 'route' tool most likely hides these entries deliberately, but it is also outdated and unable to fully show routing information kept by modern Linux kernels, so use:

```
ip -4 route show table local
ip -6 ro ls tab local
```

(Note: This is Linux-specific. In BSDs, there is usually just one routing table and `netstat -rn` would show you special routes with the `l` flag set. In other operating systems it may even be just built-in behavior and not necessarily exposed as routes at all.)

Additionally, the addresses don't even have to be on the same interface, because the packets **never actually use the physical interface**. Instead the kernel behaves as if its own addresses were simply routed over the *loopback* interface 'lo'.

> Question #2: Why can IP addresses on different subnets & interfaces communicate without IP forwarding enabled? Is it because they belong to the same host? Where is this behavior defined? I.e. would IP forwarding rules only kick in once packets start leaving the host?

Yes, it's because they belong to the same host. (On Linux they also need to be on the same network namespace, e.g. same container.)

IP forwarding rules kick in when a packet is *received* over a non-loopback interface (e.g. it came over Ethernet to the local MAC address), but its destination IP is not recognized as belonging to the host.

Locally generated packets by definition are not being "forwarded" (they are "output" as they have a local source IP address) so the forwarding rules do not apply.

Comment: Wow, that's interesting. I didn't know about the local table. Learned a lot, thanks!

Comment: I've reread your explanation. In a nutshell: If a packet is seen by iptables and the **source IP address belongs to the host**, the packet will be either a)  send to its local destination (loopback-like traffic) b) be send to link local destination (layer 2 net) or c) it'll be routed to a gateway (internet). If, on the other hand, the source IP address **does not belong to the host**, forwarding rules apply. Is this correct?